# How to use a python virtual environment copied to a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have a python package I have installed and modified to my needs stored in a venv folder. I thought using:

```
RUN source venv/bin/activate
```

in my Dockerfile (after copying it into the container of course) would solve my problems but the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25086628/2246776) revealed that it doesn't. Afterwards, I came across [this article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-virtualenv-dockerfile/) that shows how to set up a new venv inside a docker container but doesn't answer my question. Many other answers sent me on a neverending wild chase so I decided to ask here. Hopefully a good answer will solve my problem and serve those who will face this problem in the future for custom python packages in docker containers.

**My question:**
How to use a venv copied into a docker container?

Comment: Usually the virtual environment is rebuild from the `requirements.txt` during the build of the image.

Comment: Right, but then the packages won’t have my custom changes.

Comment: Then you add your custom packages to the build process.

Comment: Just copy them over to the folder? Or there’s something else I’m missing here?

Comment: If the packages contain C code it is unlikely to work properly.

Comment: I’ve changed some py files. There’s no c code. Only the python packages with some changes in the py files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can't copy virtual environments anywhere, Docker or otherwise.  They tend to be tied to a very specific filesystem path and a pretty specific Python installation.  If you knew you had the *exact* same Python binary, and you copied it to the *exact* same filesystem path, you could probably COPY it in as-is, but the build system would be extremely fragile.

It's also the case that you usually don't need virtual environments in Docker.  A Docker image provides the same sort of isolated Python installation that you'd use a virtual environment for in a non-Docker context.  If you'd ordinarily set up a virtual environment by running

```sh
python3 -m venv vpy
. vpy/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then you can get an equivalent installation with a Dockerfile like

```sh
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In comments you hint at hand-modifying installed packages.  This isn't usually a best practice (what if there's a critical security update in a package you've changed? what if your colleague needs to work on your project but not on your computer?).  You can use a tool like **diff**(1) to make a patch file describing what's changed, comparing your modified file with the original.  If you have that, then you can do something like

```sh
COPY local.patch /app/
RUN cd $(python3 -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path("platlib"))') \
 && patch -p0 < /app/local.patch
```

It's important to note that each RUN command starts a new shell in a new container.  So the `cd` command in this last example *only* affects this RUN command and nothing later.  In your proposed `RUN source ...` command, the environment variables set by this will be lost at the end of that RUN command.  (Also note that `source` is not a standard shell command and won't work on, for instance, Alpine-based images, but `.` is equivalent and is standard.)